# Capture exception raising frame in Python

Tags: python, debugging, exception, logging, error-logging

I want a more detailed error log.

Specifically, I'd like to access the `f_locals` of an exception raising frame from inside an except clause.

```
def dumb_raiser(string: str):
    if not isinstance(string, str):  
        raise ValueError("Yup")

try:
    dumb_raiser(1)
except ValueError as ex:
    #  grab f_locals from frame and log here
    pass
```

How would you access the necessary frame to do this?

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to simply tack on the function's `locals()` to the exception when you raise it:

```
def dumb_raiser(string: str):
    if not isinstance(string, str):  
        raise ValueError("Yup", locals())

try:
    dumb_raiser(1)
except ValueError as ex:
    print(ex.args[1])
```

This prints: `{'string': 1}`, as you'd expect.

Comment: There is still the problem of catching an exception from a library I didn't write, which is the majority of my exception handling.

Comment: @thismachinechills Are you sure that the stack frame still exists once the library function raises the exception and returns to the calling code? I don't believe it does. You might have to do something with `sys.settrace` to keep it alive.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best way (you could also examine the stackframes here) but the idea is to just use a decorator.

```
def derp(f):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            f(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as ex:
            raise ValueError("Failed args %s" % args)
    return wrapped


def dumb_raiser(string):
    if not isinstance(string, str):
        raise ValueError("Yup")

try:
    dumb_raiser = derp(dumb_raiser)
    dumb_raiser(1)
except ValueError as ex:
    print ex.message
```

Obviously you could do whatever you want to in the decorated exception handling.  I just re-raised a ValueError with a simple string to show the passed arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull from Sentry's [Python client](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-python/blob/6e75e1d5e87c4bc1a2b3486b8f53a43d4431f07c/raven/utils/stacks.py#L179), which captures stack locals with `f_locals`.